# How to add an item to a "List<EntityType> in model " with the TextBoxFor, to facilitate unobstrusive client validation MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, unobtrusive-validation

I am using a List in my viewmodel that I wish to validate on the view(using Razor view  on MVC3) using unobtrusive client validation with models.

I am trying to collect a new person info from form with validation and then adding it to the list in the view model. But using the TextBoxFor I have no choise but to use specific item in the collection which is not how it must work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class Person
{
        [Required(ErrorMessage="First name is a Required Field")]        
        public string FirstName
        { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is a Required Field")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Primary E-Mail is a Required Field")]
        public string PrimaryEmail { get; set; }

        public string PrimaryPhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So are you asking how to have more than one item from each entity type as an option in your dropdown? what kind of validation you're adding ?

Comment: I want to add another 'Person' item onto my list collecting the field values from the Form. That would be collecting all person information with Fname,Lname etc. fields and then adding it to the List<Person> in my model

Comment: What problem exactly you're having here? Is it with persisting Person data in database or retrieving it from database to your ViewModel list ?

Comment: Well I am unable to get a way to use the model fields directly from form and add it to the list in my model, taking care all of the other defined attribute validations work etc. work just the same.

the issue is i cant use '@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PersonList[Index].FirstName' , i do have some not so elegant ways to achive this but then I am looking for any elegent / builtin way to handle this

Comment: Please show us your controller method code and your view code. It looks like you're trying to achive something simple in a very complex way :)

Comment: @torm : you are correct, I just tried to have an  elegent method and ended-up complicating the whole process. Just used simple basics and have it working good :)

thank you

Comment: post your new code as an answer so if someone will have similar problem will be able to fix it :) gl

Answer (score 1):

I've done this by adding a property to my ViewModel which exposes a new person instance.

```
public class PeopleModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Person> People { get; set; }
    public Person NewPerson { get; set; }
}
```

You don't even have to assign a value to it, the existence of the property is enough.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var data = new PeopleModel {People = getPeople()};
    return View(data);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("MakeNew", "People", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPerson.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewPerson.FirstName)
}
```

and finally in your action that receives the new data:

```
public ActionResult MakeNew(Person newPerson)
{
    return Content(newPerson.FirstName);
}
```